# Align div left with minimum margin that floats offscreen on resize

Tags: css

My CSS vocabulary is failing me.  I'm sure this can be done but I don't know how to state my question correctly.... CSS/HTML really isn't my thing :(

Basically, what I'd like to do is have a main div and a border div.  The main div will be 700px wide and centered.  The border div will be 300px wide and either:

1. Aligned to the left of the screen if the screen size is larger than 1000px (300px+700px=1000px)
2. Pushed off the screen if the screen size is less than 1000px.  For example, if the browser were 800px wide, the border div would be positioned left-200px (700px-1000px=-200px).

I hope that makes some sense.  Here is the sample code for my question.  If you try it in a browser (in my case FF), you'll find that when the browser screen is larger than 1000px the center is 'centered' and the border is aligned 'left.'  However if you adjust the browser size the border stays 'left' instead of pushing off screen, and the center drops down.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #border {
            background-color: red;
            width:300px;
            height:900px;
            float:left;
        }

        #center {
            background-color: yellow;
            width:700px;
            height:900px;
            float:left;
            left:50%;
    }
</style>
</head>    
<body>
    <div id="border"></div>
    <div id="center">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this will be close to what you want.

```
#container{margin-left:300px;}
#border {
         background-color: red;
         width:300px;
         height:900px;
         position:absolute;
         top:0;
         left:0;
}

#center {
         background-color: yellow;
         width:700px;
         height:900px;
         margin:0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #container{margin-left:0;float:right;width:700px;}
    #border{left:auto;right:700px;}
}
```

The HTML has been updated to include a wrapper for your center div in container div. The basics are.

### #border

- position: absolute. Removes the div out of the document flow.
- top, left. Place the border at the top left of the page.

### #container

- margin-left. Adds a margin to clear the border div.

### #center

- margin:0 auto. Causes the div to be centered within its parent

### @media screen and (max-width: 1000px){}

This is a CSS3 selector that will cause alternate styles to be used when the screen is narrower than 1000px.

#### #container

- float:right. Causes the container to align to the right of the screen.

#### #border

- right:700px. Positions the right side of `#border` to be 700px from the right side of the screen. Causes the div to slide off the left side of the screen as the screen shrinks.

Due to use of CSS3 functionality this will only work in compliant browsers. Ensure that you test in all supported browsers.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and come up with something for IE8 and down.  But this is a great start that explains everything very well.

Comment: I simply added a conditional JS include for IE8 and below with a jquery function that mimics the media max-width by applying the correct css if the browser is less than 1000px.  Jquery functions used were .resize() and .width() if anybody sees this and is curious. Obviously wont work if JS is disabled, but you can't please everyone and I'm just a volunteer :P